# Program not reading text file properly outside of netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I've run into a weird problem with netbeans; my program needs to read a csv file and get the first two columns from it. I am using opencsv to do the parsing. After I built my program and tried to run the jar outside of netbeans, The program didn't behave as it should. After much, much debugging trying to figure out what is going wrong, I've managed to narrow down the problem just a little bit.

My program is supposed to read kanji from a text file. And it does so very well while inside netbeans. But if I try to run it outside of netbeans, two things happen.

1) It doesn't read in the right characters. If I output everything I read in into a new csv file, then instead of getting kanji, I get characters like: ä¼š and é«ª. The second column of my csv file is in English and that gets read in and written out properly.

2) It doesn't read all the lines; when I counted how many lines were being read, inside the IDE that number was correct. But outside of it, I am missing about 100 or so lines.

Can any one help me figure out why this might be happening? I've never worked with anything but English so character encoding is a bit foreign to me. But I did check in netbeans and the encoding is set to utf-8.

Edit: code as requested in comment. Though I don't know if this will be that helpful. The variable map is a hashmap.

```
private void loadNames() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file));
                String[] line;
                while ((line = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                    map.put(line[0], line[1]);
                }
//debug code
int counter = 0;
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("test.txt"), ',', 
CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER, 
CSVWriter.NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER, 
System.getProperty("line.separator"));
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()){
String[] string = {entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()};
writer.writeNext(string);
counter++;
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, counter);


            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                ErrorHandler.displayError("ka_data.csv file not found in    folder Data");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ErrorHandler.displayError("error at readNext");
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();

}
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I posted the code that reads the file.

Comment: Have you tried manually setting the charset when reading the file in? I admit I've never used CSV lib you are referencing, but what happens if you try `new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));` I'm wondering if this is a default charset issue.

Comment: Yep, that was it. It's reading all the lines and I used an OutputStreamWriter to write the files and it shows everything is as it should be. Could I trouble you to leave an answer so that I can mark this question as solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried manually setting the charset when reading the file in? I suspect you have a default charset issue. Try:

```
new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
```